# Is it possible to convert a Function object to a byte array in dart?

Tags: dart, reflection, eval, objectbox

I have a dart class which contains a Function member variable (which is different for each instance of the class). I need to store instances of this class in a database (such as ObjectBox), but in order to do so, I have to convert the Function to something that ObjectBox can handle.

I have seen that (using isolates) I could store the function as a string and then execute the string in a similar manner to JS eval(), but this feels like it is prone to errors and I'm hoping there's a better way of storing an actual function (not to mention isolates only working in JIT mode).

I can't see any obvious way to do this, but I'm hoping somebody here knows something I don't!

Comment: Functions resist being serialized.  There's no easy way.  They can be sent to an Isolate only with a lot of shenanigans.  You'll need to rethink your strategy... perhaps create configured-controller objects where the configuration can be serialized.

Comment: Hmm, OK cheers -- how about producing an AST from the function and storing that, then re-producing the original function from it when I retrieve from the DB? Or is that just the same problem by a different name?

Comment: Yes, you can invent a tiny interpreter and do what you wish.  It's reasonable to solve for a small limited set of operations, but you'll likely never get all of dart to go through an ASCII pipe unless you have a complete dart compiler on the other end and kept the dart source around locally to send.